# 乘 vs 承 - are they related?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

Just learnt a few verbs which use 乘 and 承 and was thinking that, not only do they look and sound mighty similar, but their ultimate meanings are both related to 'transfering' something. 乘 with vehicles from one place to another and 承 with transferring responsibility (承担) or transferring guilt (承认). 
Anyone know if they stem from the same root? If so, how did they come to be different?
Hashamyim

Comment: 乘= ride (on above) ; 承= hold up ( from under)/ take on

Answer (score 11, accepted):

「乘」and「承」do indeed sound similar, but an etymological relation (if any) would be *before* the time of [Old Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese). They are unrelated, as far as usage or glyph origins is concerned.

> ## 乘
>
> 「乘」was originally a picture of a person「大」climbing on top of a tree「木」; *feet*「舛」were added on to the person later (Shape #2 onwards).
>
> ## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [粹](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1109
> [合集6491](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6491&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 公臣簋
> [集成4186](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4186&jgwfl=)</kbd>
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> The original meanings were *to ascend, to ride an object*, extended to mean *to take advantage of [a situation]*. It does not mean *to transfer*, which is a coincidence due to its meaning of *ride*.
>
> ---
>
> ## 承
>
> 「承」was originally a picture of two hands「」and「又」holding up a kneeling person「卩」. The kneeling person's legs were straightened (Shape #2), then replaced with another hand「手」to emphasise the meaning of *holding up*, leaving behind a small shape representing the rest of the person (Shape #3 onwards).
>
> ## <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.30.12
> [合集9175](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=9175&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)
> 金
> [image]
> 令狐君嗣子
> [集成9719](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9719&jgwfl=)</kbd>
> <kbd>篆
> [image]
> 說文解字</kbd>
> 　<kbd>現代
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>
>
> The original meaning was *to hold up*, extended to mean *to carry responsibility > to inherit, carry on, continue*. *To transfer* may give a wrong impression if used incorrectly; it is only related in the sense of *to inherit, carry on, continue*.

## References:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

Comment: Wow - very authoritative answer - thanks for taking the time to provide the info :-)